# what is the deep meaning of chapter 2 verse 28 Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

**Gita chapter 2 verse 28**:

> avyaktadini bhutani
> vyakta-madhyani bharata
> avyakta-nidhanany eva
> tatra ka paridevana

Can anybody explain the meaning of this verse in detail?

Comment: Which is the translation you are trying to understand?

Comment: @Pandya actually , i was confused on ''avyaktadini bhutani vyakta-madhyani'.But is now cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verse Gita 2.28 is:

> Mystery surrounds the origin of beings. Mysterious too is their end.
> Only in the interim between birth and death are they manifested
> clearly. Such being the case, what is there to grieve about?

**Gita 2.28**

It seems from this verse that even Lord Krishna does not know the origin of beings and their end. Thus it is a puzzling verse. In reality there is a simple explanation. The Lord is telling Arjuna that there is no reason to grieve even if you are not a believer in the Atman. Of course origin and death become mysterious from the non-believer's point of view.

> This and the succeeding verse seems to refer to some school of
> naturalism, which accepts no immortal spirit. Death becomes a natural
> and no doubt a mysterious and unavoidable phenomenon.

**Commentary on Gita 2.28 by Swami Tapasyananda**

Answer (score 1):

Lord Krishna trying to say here that atma always stays and so that's why unborn,and when a person acquires body,he takes birth which is meaning of vyaktani Madhya and when atma goes from body at time of death,after that it is also alive but not in any body so again in avaykta form .So what is conveying to arjun as main message that it is body which will die but atma remain forever.

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The rules insist on deriving the answer based on scriptures or great acharyas. Hope you have a good time on the site :)